# Silverlight custom class & Name attribute

Tags: silverlight, xaml

Just sample of behavior:

```
namespace XAMLParserBug
{
   public class MyCustomClass
   {
      public int ID { get; set; }
      public string Name { get; set; }
   }
}
```

then use it in XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="XAMLParserBug.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:XAMLParserBug"
    mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="640" d:DesignHeight="480">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <local:MyCustomClass ID="1" Name="My Name With Spaces" />
    </UserControl.Resources>
 <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
```

and then get the error:

> 'My Name With Spaces' is not a valid value for Name

Is it a XAML parser bug or well-known behavior?

---

**Added:**

Anyway, WPF XAML parser correctly processed Name property in this case (VS 2008 SP1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According the MSDN documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189026%28VS.95%29.aspx#UsingNamescopesatRuntime) :

> Each object element with a Name or x:Name attribute defined in the markup generates an
>   internal field with a CLR name that matches the XAML name.

Hence any content in a Name property must conform to the rules for field identifier names.

Personnally I would have expected XAML to only create fields for items with using the `x:Name` form and relax its rules for `Name` at least for non-UIElement types but it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use Name as a property in XAML: it is reserved by x:Name.

Comment: Where described this limitation? Why xml namespaces (x:) are ignored?

Answer (score 0):

The Naming Grammar for XAML are found here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742534.aspx

None of the characters mentioned is a "space" so therefore the following is not allowed:

```
My Name With Spaces
```

However this is allowed:

```
MyNameWithSpaces
```

One of your comments makes me wonder (sorry if I am wrong) that you may be confusing namespaces with Names with Spaces as these concepts are seperate, as a namespace would be like:

```
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
```

With the reference using a namespace below:

```
x:Name="ObjectName"
```

Comment: No, i am not confusing about xml namespaces. 

In my example `Name`-attribute is my custom property of string type and with no limitations. But XAML parser considered it as `x:Name` attribute that has special meaning and grammar limitations.

My thougths about it: That behavior is a bug in XAML-parser. This limitation has meaning only for `FrameworkElement`-based classes.

Comment: Hey sorry about that, must have mis-understood, but usually Name is reserved - so maybe it is that I think you may be on the right lines - I have had some parser errors from XAML that I were for non-specific reasons!